WSO2 7.0.0 User ID Claim Setup Issue When we are trying to Migrate from 5.11.0
We are using opensource 5.11.0 Wso2is Identity Server. Created one Identity Provider which will integrate with Office365 and with custom claims like below Image.

For the above Identity Provider we created one Service Provider and mapped the claims as below Image.

It was working absolutely fine.
Now we are trying to Migrate latest version 7.0.0.
Where I created Identity provider as Connection with below claim configuration.

Also Created Service Provider as Application but there is not way to map the EmailAddress as Subject Claim.


With this configuration, in the JWT token level under sub we are getting some guid id instead of EmailAddress. Also in 5.11.0 we have option to export Service provider and import service provider.  In 7.0.0 there is no option to import. If anyone knows how to create custom claims in applications for IDP let me know.
I tried Manually changing data in tables copying from 5.11.0 to 7.0.0. Its not working.

It is possible to assign an alternate subject identifier for service provider in IS 7.0.0

Select email as the requested attribute for the SP
Save the changes
Enable Assign alternate subject identifier
Check the generated drop down list

Refer:

